# AWS domain certificate ARN in public repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a certificate for my domain `*.myWebSiteIsCool.com`; I'm trying to learn `cloudformation` writing templates and consuming external plugins. For one of these plugins, 
I need to include the ARN of my certificate. Example:     `arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:573882838883:certificate/1523875e-b508-4406-9c7f-553698657454`

To the best of my knowledge, ARNs, are just identifiers inside AWS world. But, I should ask to avoid committing big mistakes, is there any security concern of having that cloudformation template with the ARN (this ARN or any other) in a public repository? Can people somehow use an ARN to "exploit" and obtain sensitive information?

Thanks for any advice. I'm new and want to do the things properly.

Comment: It is good practice to avoid publishing account related information into the public repository.There is no direct way for someone to access the certificate but you never no.

Comment: @Peter what plugins are you referring to? I am not aware of that feature in cloud formation

Comment: there are bad people out there who want to harm you :). They are building a profile of you. They build the profile with every detail they know about you. anyways, can't you use a private repo

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct security risk in storing ARNs in public repos. No one will be able to access the certificate or your account, and, assuming you have strong passwords and MFA enabled, all your data and your account are secure.

There is a some information leakage you should be aware of. It is easy to observe what region you are in and your account ID. But that is no great risk IMHO. It would be very hard to exploit a hack on your account with just that data.